# ¿Como puedo hacer un botón cancelar multimodal con tkinter python vinculado a sqLite?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, funciones, botón, sqlite3

estoy haciendo un proyecto en Python vinculado a una base de datos en sqLite3, necesito que me ayuden a hacer el botón cancelar, tengo que hacer que el botón funcione con los otros 4, "grabar", "editar", "eliminar" y "buscar". Los 4 botones tienen ventanas emergentes. Ya limpia los campos de datos y lo demás, necesito que cierre las ventanas emergentes de manera multimodal. A lo que voy es que necesito que el botón "cancelar" cierre todo y deje el treview limpio. tengo el botón cancelar así:

````
       # Botón para cancelar una operación
       self.btnCancelar = ttk.Button(self.frm2)
       self.btnCancelar.configure(text='Cancelar', width=int(bwidth*0.12), command= lambda: [self.limpiaCampos(), self.limpiaTreeview()])
       self.btnCancelar.place(anchor="nw", width=bwidth, x=int(ancho*0.28)+4*bwidth, y=col1_2)
       # self.btnGrabar.bind('<Button>', self.borrar_datos)

#Funciones Cancelar
   
   def cerrar_ventana():
       self.ventana1.withdraw() 
       
   
   def limpiaTreeview(self):
       tabla_TreeView = self.treeProductos.get_children()

       for linea in tabla_TreeView:
           self.treeProductos.delete(linea) ```
````

Comment: Hola Juan, ¿cual es el problema o error concreto que tienes? En principio simplemnte es llamar al metodo withdraw o destroy de cada ventana TopLevel que tengas en la callback del boton.¿El botón esta en la ventana principal o en alguna de las secundarias?

Comment: Hola, Bro, el problema es que necesito que el botón cierre las ventanas emergentes que se crean en el programa, necesito que el botón haga lo que hace normalmente un botón cancelar. El botón esta en la ventana principal del treeview. Otra cosa, el proyecto es con Progamación orientada a objetos, todo el programa esta dentro de una sola clase. No puedo usar esos metodos para las ventanas emergentes porque el botón no funciona cuando se crean, no deja usarlo, necesito hacer ese botón de tal manera sea multimodal :D